# Forms Authentication Timeout Being Ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, forms-authentication

I'm using asp.net Forms Authentication to require users to log in when they visit a specific page. I want the users to have to log in again after 5 minutes of inactivity but no matter what I put in the Timeout value of the forms section in the web.config the user only gets kicked off after the session state expires.

One of the tests I've tried involves this configuration:

```
<system.web>   
<sessionState timeout="1" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/authentication" timeout="2" slidingExpiration="true"/>
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

If I log in and remain idle for a minute I am asked to log in again if I refresh the page. However, I was under the impression that I should be able to continue working until the forms authentication timeout expires. I understand that at the 1 minute mark it would be too late for the slidingExpiration setting to renew my cookie but I should still have another minute before the cookie actually expires.

If I remove the Sessiontate timeout section I'm not asked to log in after two minutes have passed. It takes a long time(probably 30 minutes) before I'm asked to log back in. This to me sounds like I'm only asked to log back in when the sessionState expires.

Am I missing something here?

Here's the basic layout of the controllers and methods involved. First, the user tries to go to the Recruiter page:

```
public class HireController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Recruiter()
    {
      //do stuff after we've been authorized to access this page
    }
}
```

Because the user needs to be authorized they are redirected to the login page in the authentication controller:

```
public class AuthenticationController : BaseAuthenticationController
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationService AuthenticationService;
    public AuthenticationController(IAuthenticationService authService)
        : base(authService)
    {
        AuthenticationService = authService;
    }
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
    {
        var special= false;
        return View("~/Views/Login/Login.cshtml", new LoginModel(special) { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginCredentials credentials, string returnUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(GeneralError);
            }

            base.DoLogin(credentials.Username, credentials.Password);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = (ex is ApplicationException) ? ex.Message : GeneralError;
            ModelState.AddModelError("", message);
            return View("~/Views/Login/Login.cshtml", new LoginModel { Username = credentials.Username, ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

    }

    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Recruiter", "Hire");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Recruiter", "Hire");
    }
}
```

Here is the BaseAuthenticationController class:

```
  public class BaseAuthenticationController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationService AuthenticationService;
    protected const string GeneralError = "Login failure please try again";

    public BaseAuthenticationController(IAuthenticationService authService)
    {
        AuthenticationService = authService; 
    }

    public void DoLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        AuthenticationService.Login(username, password);
    }
}
```

Here is the concrete IAuthenticationService class:

```
 public class WebAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private const string InvalidError = "Invalid User Credentials Please try again";
    private const string LockoutError = "You have been locked out of the Hiring Center. You will receive an email shortly once your password has been reset.";
    readonly string uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HiringLoginApiBaseUrl"];
    private readonly ISecurityContext SecurityContext; 

    public WebAuthenticationService(ISecurityContext securityContext)
    {
        SecurityContext = securityContext; 
    }

    private LoginResult GetUserLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
            });
            var postResult = httpClient.PostAsync("/api/Login/Post", content).Result;                
            var loginResult = postResult.Content.ReadAsAsync<LoginResult>().Result;

            return loginResult;
        }
    }

    public MembershipProvider AuthenticationProvider
    {
        get { return Membership.Provider; }
    }

    public void Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        var loginResult = this.GetUserLogin(userName, password);
        if (!loginResult.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(InvalidError);
        }

        if (loginResult.IsLockedOut)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(LockoutError);
        }

        // Maintain the location
        IUser current = SecurityContext.Current;

        SecurityContext.SetCurrent(User.CreateAuthorized(userName, current.Location, current.Preferences));
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);

    }
}
```

I'm not too clear on what the point is of the following line is in the WebAuthenticationService class:

```
SecurityContext.SetCurrent(User.CreateAuthorized(userName, current.Location, current.Preferences));
```

the SetCurrent() method is defined as follows:

```
 public class HttpSecurityContext : ISecurityContext
{
    public static string SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY = "SECURITY_CONTEXT";

    public IUser Current
    {
        get
        {
            IUser user = HttpContext.Current.User as IUser;
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Context user is invalid;");
            }
            return user;
        }
    }

    public void SetCurrent(IUser user)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.User = user;
    }
}
```

Web.Config Membership Provider:

```
      <membership>
      <providers>
          <clear />
          <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=asdfasf" connectionStringName="mydb" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
     </membership>
```

Comment: What is the name of view for login in your app?  Normally developers have a view called `Login`, in which case `loginUrl="~/authentication/Login"` in the config for forms element.

Comment: The view itself is called Login.cshtml. The `loginUrl="~/authentication"` setting fires off the Index method in the authentication controller which in turn takes the user to the Login.cshtml view after checking if the ModelState is valid. The login logic seems to work ok for the most part. The only thing that's off is the interval after which the user is logged off and is asked to re-enter their credentials.

Comment: May be you should try with `loginUrl="~/authentication/Login"`. I do not know what your app requirements are, but for redirecting a user to login page, there should not be any need to check ModelState. However, when you are calling the Login action with HttpPost i.e. when user submits his/her credentials, then you need to check ModelState. So I am guessing, you have not wired up the authentication part correctly.

Comment: Your suggestion would not work because there is no action method called Login in the Authentication controller. As I said before, the redirection works fine. The thing that doesn't work properly is the time at which the user is asked to log in again. The user seems to be getting logged off when the sessionState times out and not when the forms timeout expires.

Comment: Also, are you using any code to create forms authentication cookie/ticket because if you are then there may be an issue with that code?

Comment: @Sunil please see my edits above. I've added a significant amount of code to give a clearer picture of how the app works. As you'll see, we are not creating a cookie/ticket from scratch so the forms authentication timeout in the web.config should be honored.

Comment: When you debug your code for login view, is the line of code `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);` being reached and executed successfully when user submits the credentials. That line of code is correct but I would make sure that its being executed.

Comment: That line is definitely being hit when I debug. In fact, if I run `FormsAuthentication.Timeout` in the immediate window right after the line is hit I get `{00:02:00}`. That tells me that the timeout in the web.config is being picked up but for some reason is being ignored.

Comment: Since your situation appears complex, I would recommend to  try a plain vanilla version of forms authentication in your MVC app. You seem to be having some non-standard stuff like going to Index rather than Login for login and there is a Membership provider. If the plain vanilla version also fails, then it might be easier to debug than  your current set up. Also, just use a simple logic like `if(userName == "bruno" && password =="1234") { //login succeeds} else { //show invalid credentials }.  Try this simple version in your app and go from there.

Comment: this is in continuation of last comment. If plain vanilla version succeeds, then use an incremental approach to change to your current setup step-by-step. So, first add the non-standard configuration of going to Index instead of Login and see if it works. Don't add membership provider at this stage. If it does not work then you know there is some issue with using Index instead of Login in forms config.  If this step succeeds, then add the membership provider and remove the simple user name / password check. Use this incremental approach to accurately find the source of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of all my problems. I found a bunch of code in global.asax that manipulates the user's session and essentially overrides forms authentication. This code runs on every request to the server and keeps the user logged in as long as they are still authenticated in the session. This means that even if the forms auth cookie expired(which it did!) the user would remain logged in. I'm guessing the previous developers started out with forms auth and then decided to write their own thing for some reason. We decided to change the session timeout so that users would be logged out after 5 minutes instead of the default 20.

Here is some of the code from global.asax that is responsible for me almost going bald:

```
 protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute()
    {
        HttpSessionState session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        if (session == null)
            return;

        IUser user = (session[HttpSecurityContext.SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY] as IUser) ?? CreateUser();
        securityContext.SetCurrent(user);
    }

    protected void Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute()
    {
        HttpSessionState session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        if (session == null) return;

        session[HttpSecurityContext.SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY] = securityContext.Current;
    }

 private IUser CreateUser()
    {
        IUserLocation location = LocateUser();
        IUser user = Common.Security.User.CreateAnonymous(location);
        SetupUserPreferences(user);
        return user;
    }
```

And this is what we changed in web.config for the session timeout:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="5"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just use wrong parameter value for `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` method. As per documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/twk5762b(v=vs.110).aspx second parameter sets persistent cookie if set to true. Otherwise cookie is not persisted and lost on session timeout. So if you want to preserve authentication cookie through different sessions (after session timeout) then use this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
```

However keep in mind that after session timeout user will lost all his session variables and that may cause errors in your web app.

Comment: I tried using a persistent cookie as well but it didn't work because we were completely ignoring forms auth even though it was turned on(see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following to the web.config file to prevent unauthorized users from accessing the page:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Apparently this is pretty standard procedure and I'm surprised I didn't run into it much earlier in my search. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx) msdn article actually mentions adding that section.

Comment: It looks like this sends users to the login page no matter which page they hit. They're only supposed to go to the login page if they attempt to go to a particular page. (sigh) back to the drawing board.

Comment: Did this solve your problem of being timed out after 1 minute?

Comment: It did not actually. It worked in the sense that users would be logged out after 1 minute as desired but it would redirect users visiting ANY page on the site to the login page. They should only be taken to the login page if they try to visit the Hire/Recruiter page since it's marked with the Authorize attribute.

Comment: I think there is a problem somewhere else in your app, since `forms authentication timeout` is not being respected.

Comment: Do you have any configuration for Membership provider in web config?

Comment: There could be an issue with your membership provider configuration since your code is not standard login code.

Comment: We do have a configuration for Membership provider in the web.config. I've added it to my question above. Could you elaborate on which part of our code is not standard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117740/discussion-between-bruno-and-sunil).

Comment: First you have login url that does not point to a login page but to an index page. Second, you should be using a method on membership provider called `ValidateUser` as per standards of using Membership provider, but your code is not doing this. The more complex and convulated you make it, the more issues its going to have.  Third, you should simply call login method of some service from controller method of Login and the service method should call membership provider's ValidateUser method.

Comment: I can tell you right now that the url is not the problem because as I've said several times before, the redirection works. Your second and third points might be worth looking into so I'll take a look at those. Thanks.

Comment: If you want I can post a simple sample with forms authentication in MVC app that works all the time.

Comment: Sure, that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I will post the sample tomorrow morning.

Comment: You can download the sample from this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzhl0S7bXwuyN2xzQlVPLXIxRVU/view?usp=sharing. Note that it's in Visual Studio 2010, but you can view Account controller and how it is used to login. I have commented the call to `ValidateUser` in Logon method of Account controller to make it simple to login using user name of sunil and password as 1234. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the sample Sunil, it's definitely a good learning tool for how forms authentication is supposed to work.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, in your situation, try setting the session timeout equal to forms authentication timeout and then  check if forms authentication timeout is respected. If yes, then there could be some code in your app that logs out a user based on some session variable value.